# How do I specialize a trait function?

Tags: rust

I have a trait for BLAS functionality:

```
pub trait Blas {
    fn gemv<F>(&self, trans: Transpose,
               cols: usize, rows: usize, matrix: &[F], matrix_factor: F,
               vector: &[F], vector_inc: usize, vector_factor: F,
               result: &[F], result_inc: usize) -> Result<(), Error>;
    ...
}
```

Now I want to make a type which implements this trait:

```
pub struct CudaBlas {
    ...
}

impl Blas for CudaBlas {
    ...
}
```

The problem is that I need separate specialisations for `gemv<f32>` and `gemv<f64>`: each one should call a dedicated shared library function. Didn't succeed to express that without compiler complaints. How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE:**

I tried the [method proposed by Jonas Tepe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855136/155423) and it doesn't seem to work. Here is the purified example:

```
trait Trait<T> {
    fn func(&self, arg: T);
}

struct Struct {
    field: usize,
}

impl Trait<f32> for Struct {
    fn func(&self, arg: f32) {
        println!("32bits: {}", arg);    
    }
}

impl Trait<f64> for Struct {
    fn func(&self, arg: f64) {
        println!("64bits: {}", arg);
    }
}

struct Struct2<T> {
    field2: T,
}

// yes, I plan to use my CudaBlas inside some generic NeuralNet<T>
impl<T> Struct2<T> {
    fn func2(&self, arg: T) {
        let s = Struct{field: 1};
        s.func(arg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s32 = Struct2::<f32>{field2: 1f32};
    let s64 = Struct2::<f64>{field2: 2f64};
    s32.func2(1f32);
    s64.func2(1f64);
}
```

I get:

> error: the trait `Trait<T>` is not implemented for the type `Struct` [E0277]

Making `Struct` to be generic doesn't solve the problem as well (the compiler complaints that `func` is not found for type `Struct<T>`). Just amazed how restrictive the Rust generics are.

Comment: What you want is a work in progress known as "impl specialization". I don't think it is implemented yet. https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210

Comment: You have significantly altered your question by putting in new context that you didn't originally include. That should probably be a separate question and I encourage you to use the "purified" example as it's easier to reason about than your original non-[MCVE](/help/mcve) example. The [solution provided by Jonas Tepe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33855136/155423) is the current best solution, until specialization exists. *Just amazed how restrictive the Rust generics are* — they are "restrictive" because the compiler is preventing you from shooting your own foot.

Comment: Why do I need generics if I cannot use them in another generic context? Otherwise I could just write two functions: gemv32 and gemv64.

Comment: Because `T` means *any type*, and your function doesn't work with any type any more, it only works with two very specific ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I needed is to add `where CudaBlas: Blas<T>`:

```
#![allow(dead_code, unused_variables)]

trait Blas<T> {
    fn gemv(&self, arg: T);
}

struct CudaBlas {
    field: usize,
}

impl Blas<f32> for CudaBlas {
    fn gemv(&self, arg: f32) {
        println!("f32");
    }
}

impl Blas<f64> for CudaBlas {
    fn gemv(&self, arg: f64) {
        println!("f64");
    }
}

struct NeuralNet<T> {
    field: T,
}

impl<T> NeuralNet<T> {
    fn process(&self, arg: T) where CudaBlas: Blas<T> {
        let cblas = CudaBlas{field:0};
        cblas.gemv(arg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let nn = NeuralNet{field:0f64};
    nn.process(12f64);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to make your trait `Blas` generic with respect to the floating point type and then have two separate implementations of this trait for your `CudaBlas struct`:

```
pub trait Blas<F> {
    fn gemv(&self, trans: Transpose,
               cols: usize, rows: usize, matrix: &[F], matrix_factor: F,
               vector: &[F], vector_inc: usize, vector_factor: F,
               result: &[F], result_inc: usize) -> Result<(), Error>;
    ...
}

impl Blas<f32> for CudaBlas {
    fn gemv(&self, trans: Transpose,
            cols: usize, rows: usize, matrix: &[f32], matrix_factor: f32,
            vector: &[f32], vector_inc: usize, vector_factor: f32,
            result: &[f32], result_inc: usize) -> Result<(), Error> {
           // implement f32 specific functionality
     }
}

impl Blas<f64> for CudaBlas {
        fn gemv(&self, trans: Transpose,
                cols: usize, rows: usize, matrix: &[f64], matrix_factor: f64,
                vector: &[f64], vector_inc: usize, vector_factor: f64,
                result: &[f64], result_inc: usize) -> Result<(), Error> {
               // implement f64 specific functionality
         }

}
```

After that you can call the method `gemv()` on your `CudaBlas` with `f32` or `f64` every time with the desired type specific results.

Comment: Yes, I know about this crutch and I'm afraid that is what I will have to do in my case.

Comment: If Blas has more methods, then I would separate the method gemv() into its own trait and implement this trait for CudaBlas. That way you avoid having to implement a whole bunch of other methods just for this distinction.

Comment: What about making it an associated type?

Comment: Would it help? I am not sure, since you cannot have overlapping implementations of traits based on associated types only. That would be a conflict.